# Getting the ordered list style not affect other lists

Tags: html, css

I have an `<ol>` that I'm trying to style for one page and have it no affect other lists that are on other pages or pages in the near future. The way it is set up now is how it should look but when I add a class to it to try and make it, it's own list not affecting other list.

I know that setting the `<ol>` tag by its self is considered a global attribute and will belong to all other tags a like but when I add a class to it, everything shifts upwards so that the numbers and text are no longer aligned.

So an example of what I have tried is adding a class `class="test` to the `ol` tag and then add that to the CSS style sheet like the commented code.

So just putting this out there that I changed the default way the `<ol>` list is displayed from "**1.**" to "**1)**". I would like to keep that format for this one list and for any other list that are created later on have the default numbering/display.

Any help would be great.

```css
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #cccccc;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.list-container {
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  padding-top: 15px;
}


/** example
 .test ol { 
  counter-reset: list; 
}
**/

ol {
  counter-reset: list;
}

ol>li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(list) ") ";
  counter-increment: list;
}

li>.list-paragraph {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="Header">
    <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>
    <div class="legal-stuff">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc
      vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
      nunc vel.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
          nunc vel.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
          nunc vel.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
          nunc vel.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
          nunc vel.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada
          nunc vel.</div>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"when I add a class to it, everything go all over the place."* - What does this mean?

Comment: what class are you adding that is screwing it up?

Comment: It seems fine, added a class to it and no issues in this example.

Comment: @Chev were did you add the class?

Answer (score 0):

I just added a class `.mainList` and everything is working fine. I also created another list with class '.innerList'.

[Here](https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/NWWOKzZ) is the code.

Now, when you copy the same list to other pages just replace this class name with some other class name, copy the css and replace the class name and do the changes in the styling. As long the class names are different nothing wrong will happen.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] to put the code in the body of the answer itself. Use [a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) if you want it to render inline like CodePen.

Comment: Sure cody. I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per the previous comment, I have now created a demo here where I have added the `.list` class to the ol and all seems fine based on your code example. I assume the issue lies elsewhere - possibly the name of the class you selected may be clashing.

See the snippet included:

```css
.container { 
  width: 50%; 
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #cccccc; 
  font-size: 12px; 
} 
.list-container { 
  padding-left:15%; 
  padding-right: 15%; 
  padding-top: 15px; 
}
.list {
   color: red; 
  counter-reset: list;
}
ol { 
  counter-reset: list; 
}
ol > li { 
  list-style: none; 
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

ol > li:before {
 content: counter(list) ") ";
 counter-increment: list;
}

li > .list-paragraph { 
  display: inline-block; 
  margin-left: 30px; 
  position: relative; 
  bottom: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
 <div class="Header">
  <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>
  
  <div class="legal-stuff">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="list-container">
  <ol class="list">
   <li>
    <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.</div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.</div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.</div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.</div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="list-paragraph">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel.</div>
   </li>
  </ol>
 </div>
</div>
```